# Find $\left( \frac{2}{7} \right) \left(\log_2 \frac{y}{x} \right)$ if-

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $$x= (\cos1°) (\cos2°) (\cos3°) .............(\cos89°)$$
and

$$y=(\cos 2°)(\cos 6°)(\cos 10°).............(\cos 86°)$$
Then what is the integer nearest to $$\left( \frac{2}{7} \right) \left( \log_2 \frac{y}{x} \right) ?$$

I tried putting it in $\Pi$ form but had no luck.

Comment: Ummm... where did this problem come from and why is this it interesting and worthy of our time?

Comment: It came in PRMO( Pre Regional Mathematical Olympiad) 2018.

Comment: Are you sure the question is exactly as you have written? Please verify once.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: Another computer  check gives us $19$: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F7*log%28%28prod_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7B21%7Dcos%28%282%2B4*j%29*pi%2F180%29%29%2F%28prod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B89%7Dcos%28k*pi%2F180%29%29%29%2Flog%282%29).

Comment: Let me add a picture of that question to be clear

Comment: Unable to add a photo due to some issue. I am attaching a link to the pdf of the exam paper in which this question was asked.The question is Q14.https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/PRMO18_Question_Paper.pdf

Comment: What is “putting it in $\Pi$”?

Comment: y/x can be written as $\frac{\prod_{i=0}^(89) \cosi}{\prod_{j=0}^(21) \cos(4j+2)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
x = \Bigl(\cos(1^{\circ})\cos(2^{\circ})\cdots\cos(44^{\circ})\Bigr) \cdot \cos(45^{\circ}) \cdot \Bigl(\sin(44^{\circ})\sin(43^{\circ})\cdots\sin(1^{\circ})\Bigr)\tag{1}
$$
$$
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 2^{-44} \sin(2^{\circ})\sin(4^{\circ})\cdots\sin(88^{\circ}).
$$
Next step:
denote $$z=\sin(2^{\circ})\sin(4^{\circ})\cdots\sin(88^{\circ}).\tag{2}$$
Then
$$
z = \Bigl(\sin(2^{\circ})\sin(4^{\circ})\cdots\sin(44^{\circ})\Bigr) \cdot  \Bigl(\cos(44^{\circ})\cos(42^{\circ})\cdots\cos(2^{\circ})\Bigr)\tag{3}
$$
$$
=2^{-22}\sin(4^{\circ})\sin(8^{\circ})\cdots\sin(88^{\circ})
$$
$$
=2^{-22}\cos(86^{\circ})\cos(82^{\circ})\cdots\cos(2^{\circ})
$$
$$
=2^{-22}y.
$$
Therefore:
$$
x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot 2^{-44}\cdot 2^{-22}y = 2^{-66.5}y.\tag{4}
$$
Hence
$$
\log_2(y/x) = 66.5;
$$
$$
\dfrac{2}{7}\log_2(y/x) = \dfrac{2}{7}\cdot \dfrac{133}{2} = 19.\tag{5}
$$